# Should I report about oops page?

Tags: support, 500-server-error

When something went wrong I might see the oops page like this one:

> [image: oops]

I’m slightly confused should I report about my actions which lead to such page reproducibly in the separate question tagged [bug] or developers have been already notified in full about the problem as message says?

Comment: It won't hurt if you can provide an actionable bug report on a meta site.

Comment: I would recommend raising a meta post about it. The error page says they only try to fix *some* of them, so raising a meta post increases the likelihood they'll get to it.

Comment: If you can remember what you were doing just prior to the error it might be useful to post that.

Comment: @ChrisF [here it is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306268/339911)