# Server error after switching from mobile to full site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, 500-server-error

Being on mobile web and trying to post an answer with empty body properly shows me an error:

> [image: mobile error]

This looks fine and friendly, until you switch to the full site from the bottom link on this page. This leads to a server error:

> [image: oops]

Comment: interesting fault case - why are you wanting to do that?

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm not sure that I understand you clearly. To do *what*?

Comment: Well, for some odd reason the mobile theme is not using AJAX, but rather submitting directly to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306268/answer/submit (like websites used to do before AJAX era, like 20 years ago). Since that URL only accept POST data, trying to view it in browser gives an error. They should at least give some friendly message when visiting it,  not internal error.

Comment: Why would you try to submit a blank post, and then switch to full site from the bottom link. I know it's good to conduct full testing, but how did you even come up with this one? :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop submitting a blank post was accidentally as a result of [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290780/339911) when no link is specified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views)